# NFSv4 parameter specification for exported directories and client IP

Tags: freebsd

On FreeBSD 10.1 REL (for both client and server), I'm trying to share certain directories (**/etc** and **/root**) via NFSv4 with a specific client.

My **/etc/exports** -

```
/etc /root  -ro   -maproot=nobody:nogroup   -network   10.0.200.100/32
V4: /
```

...this gives two unexpected results: 1) the entire filesystem is mountable 2) from any IP. A similar point was made [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/389189/understanding-nfs4-linux-server) for linux but doesn't seem to have been specifically answered.

My [apparently incorrect] understanding was that other directories, e.g. **/boot**, would not be shared when using this **/etc/exports** file, and that only a client with IP 10.0.200.100 would be able to mount the share. However, I can mount any directory under the server's root filesystem from any IP that I've tried using this **/etc/exports**. When running **showmount -e**, both directories are listed as exported, and running

```
service nfsd restart
service mountd onereload
```

...outputs no error messages to **/var/log/messages** on the server.

**EDIT:** I got it working based on what I learned [here](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-net/2016-October/046368.html) and [here](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/7034/). My **/etc/exports** file layout (above) was incorrect (and what you see above still is incorrect) and some errors were not turning up likely because **nfsuserd_flags** was not set to **-verbose**. Also worth mentioning here is the freebsd [exports(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?exports(5)) documentation for NFSv4 is sorely lacking and appears to be, in some cases, incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the first export line. There is a dash in front of the argument after `-network`. Also check if the network argument makes sense at all. It does not look like a network specification to me.